# TFS 2013 SSL Seetings on build and release server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

Currently we are running TFS2013 version. As per our organization support standards we are no longer recommended to enable SSL 2.0 & SSL 3.0 and as an alternative to SSL, need to implement the strongest proven version of TLS when encrypting a data transmission via ftp, the web, email or other technologies.

If we disable the SSL and implement the TSL will it affect the TFS builds or release in any way?

Comment: In all likelyhood it will break and will require you to enable strong crypto in .NET as well as optionally upgrade to a later .NET framework version on your systems: https://serverfault.com/a/843355/154975

Comment: Regardless, I'd highly recommend to upgrade TFS 2013 to 2018 anyway. 2013 is getting old and you're missing out of a lot of goodness. You're probably also on an old version of Windows Server, you may be limited in its support for strong ciphers, some of the later ciphers never made it to the older server versions. See the table on this page for an overview of supported cipher suites and windows server versions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx